# javascript change event behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Can someone explain to me the behavior of `change` event in my javascript code? I have two event-listeners attached to the search input box so when the value of input *changed* it print the changed value; when input box is *clicked* it empties the value.

---

My question is when I click the search box the value of input box changed from something to empty, so why doesn't it trigger `change` event?

```js
var search = document.querySelector("#search");
search.addEventListener("change",function(){
    console.log("change event occur");
    console.log($("#search").val());
})

var search = document.querySelector("#search");
search.addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log("click event occur");
    $("#search").val(' ');
})
```

```css
body,html{
    background-color:#092B40;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-color: transparent;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.entry{
    display: block;
    background-color: #F8ECC2;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    min-width:600px;
    height:90px;
    width: 100%;
}
.container{
    overflow:hidden;
}
#search{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
}
#wiki{
    margin-top: 0%;
    animation: 2s slide-up;
}
@keyframes slide-up{
    from{
        margin-top:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
    to{
        margin-top:0%;
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
 <title>Wiki Search API</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
 <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
    <div id='search-box' class="form-group text-center">
        <input id='search' type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
        <submit id='go-button' class='btn btn-info '>Go!</submit>
        <button id='random' class='btn btn-warning '><a href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random'>Random!</a></button>
      
    </div>
    <!--<div class='filler well'>-->
        
    <!--</div>-->
    <div id='wiki' class='row'>
            <a class="entry">
                <p>Hello</p>
            </a>
            <a class="entry">
                 <p>Hello</p>
            </a>
            <a class="entry">
                <p>Hello</p>
            </a>
            <a class="entry">
                 <p>Hello</p>
            </a>
            <a class="entry">
                <p>Hello</p>
            </a>
            <a class="entry">
                 <p>Hello</p>
            </a>
         
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Changes you make with JavaScript don't cause "change" events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because events are only raised from user input. Programmatically changing the value of an input doesn't raise an event. If you want one to occur, then you need to `trigger()` it manually, like this:

```
var search = document.querySelector("#search");
search.addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log("click event occur");
  $("#search").val('').trigger('change');
})
```

Also note that you're using an odd mix of plain JS and jQuery. It's better practice to stick to one or the other. As you've loaded jQuery, you may as well use it:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#search').on({
    change: function() {
      console.log("change event occur");
      console.log($(this).val());
    },
    click: function() {
      console.log("click event occur");
      $(this).val('').trigger('change');
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='search' type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
```

Comment: But is it really bad to mix them ? I heard that using plain js can boost performance but some jQuery functions really come in handy and  hard to not use it sometimes.

Comment: That's why it's better to use one or the other. If you use plain JS only you get the performance, but at the cost of writing more code. If you use jQuery you lose a little performance, but can write a lot less code. If you use both then you're nullifying all the benefits.

Answer (score 2):

I usually dont use `change` event with text or text-area input. I use `propertychange`

```
var search = document.querySelector("#search");
search.addEventListener("propertychange ",function(){
    console.log("change event occur");
    console.log($("#search").val());
});
```

Or with jquery you can use `propertychange` event like this:

```
$("#search").bind('input propertychange', function(){
    console.log("change event occur");
    console.log($("#search").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When the placeholder is removed from the search input that is not changing the value of the text box, it is only hiding the placeholder.